# Gremlin : Add multiple vertices in single gremlin query?

Tags: graph-databases, titan, gremlin

I am using Titan 0.4 + Cassandra. 
My use-case requires insert multiple vertices at a time.
(aprrox batch size is 100 vertices at a time.)
eg :

```
v01 = g.addVertex(["UC":"B","i":2]); v02 = g.addVertex(["UC":"H","i":1])
v03 = g.addVertex(["LC":"a"]); v04 = g.addVertex(["LC":"a"]);
v05 = g.addVertex(["LC":"d"]); v06 = g.addVertex(["LC":"h"]); 
v07 = g.addVertex(["LC":"i"]); v08 = g.addVertex(["LC":"p"]);
```

Is there any gremlin command to add all `Eight vertices in a single request`. ( something like  `g.addVertices()` ?? )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gremlin does not have an `addVertices()` wrapper - you'll need to call `addVertex()` multiple times.

Answer (score 7):

I'm using the c# SDK. What worked for me is just chaining the addV commands:

```
g.addV('item').property('id', '5aa3a51e-6434-4d53-aed4-
5db3c90e3551').addV('item').property('id', '7f859920-2251-4553-8325-
5dbb2f626d1c')
```

for your example:

```
g.addVertex(["UC":"B","i":2]).addVertex(["UC":"H","i":1]).addVertex(["LC":"a"]).addVertex(["LC":"a"]).addVertex(["LC":"d"]).addVertex(["LC":"h"]).addVertex(["LC":"i"]).addVertex(["LC":"p"])
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

I had the requirement to add several vertices at the same time too. Individual **addV** queries weren't practical for inserting thousands of record at a time, while also retrieving their database generated ids.

Here's what I came up with as a batch insertion command/query

```
g.addV('One').values('id').as('one').addV('Two').values('id').as('two').select('one', 'two')
```

CosmosDB returns

```
[{
   "one": "372be552-7f63-4d7b-be81-a73d5d677afa",
   "two": "a60d3773-5c29-454e-b079-dec734c4f431"
}]
```

Comment: You can also do this...

    g.addV('One').property('some','thing').values('id').as('1').addV('Two').values('id').as('2').select('1', '2')

And receive the id of the vertex (not the property)

Comment: For adding multiple vertices and linking to them to an existing edge at the same time g.V('652ce0c3-1c8d-475e-bd99-e89993a9d9fc').and(
    addE('has').to(g.addV('Wing1')), 
    addE('has').to(g.addV('Wing2'))
)